# Linear search to get the position to insert an item in the array

Tags: objective-c, linear-search

How to do linear I want to get the position for an item in the array to insert , I mean the index where I have to insert the data in the array. How can I achieve this by using Linear  search only . Suggestions Please.

Answer (score 0):

Linear search for example with a for loop:

```
int[] test = new int[1024]; 
// i assume you have something like this

int searchnumber = 17;

int foundindex = -1;

for(int i = 0; i < count, i++)
{
if (test[i] == 17)
{
    foundindex = i;
    break;
}
}

// now you have the found index in foundindex
```

If your array is sorted you could use a binary search, but since you asked for a linear search tghis should do the trick.

Comment: No the array wont be in sorted, but see I have an array of (4, 6 , 8 ,10 ) i want the position for the element 9 which I want to insert into the array..

Comment: But your example array is sorted, or do i get something wrong?

Comment: think tat array is sorted initally , I have an array of ( 4 , 0 , 8 ,5 , 3) for each item how can I get the best positions ?

Comment: i would sort the array in the beginning and then use a binary search. So you only have one time a little overhead and are really fast when searching items.

Comment: addign items to array will be random, so while adding to the array I need the best position

Comment: I want to get the position thro linear search.

Answer (score 0):

Find the nearest possible value and insert before or after it depending on your need

```
    loop
    {
    int index = [arrResultRow indexOfObject:10];
    [arrResultRow insertObject:object atIndex:index+1]
    }
```